# ActionBarSherlock for Android causing StackOverflowError

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I integrated ActionBarSherlock into my Android application. It is mostly working well, with one serious exception...

When running specifically on API Level 10 (which corresponds to Android 2.3.3), and only on that version, a StackOverflowError (shown below) is happening at a certain point when the user navigates between two particular activities. The call stack reveals that this error happens entirely within the Android framework, independent of my custom code.

The only reason I know it is related to ActionBarSherlock is that the error doesn't happen if I revert my changes to the activity classes so that they again inherit from the standard Activity base class instead of SherlockActivity, and revert to a non-Sherlock theme.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.android.internal.util.ArrayUtils.emptyArray(ArrayUtils.java:107)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getSpans(SpannableStringInternal.java:269)
at android.text.SpannedString.getSpans(SpannedString.java:25)
at android.text.Styled.drawUniformRun(Styled.java:67)
at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:322)
at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:381)
at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1703)
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:505)
at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4431)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1703)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6640)
at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6428)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1571)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1921)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1526)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1262)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1863)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered a similar error when `invalidateOptionsMenu()` was being called twice in very quick succession (in onResume, and then in onPrepareOptionsMenu).

Once I removed the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` calls from onPrepareOptionsMenu, the issue went away.  Maybe this isn't what's happening in your situation, but just thought I'd offer it as a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks. I unfortunately ended up not using ActionBarSherlock and simply providing the standard ActionBar only on the newer Android versions. I'll keep this in mind though.

Comment: Definitely something to consider.  I use ABS on all my apps and support back to 2.2 without any issues.  Apps look so nice with ABS :)

Answer (score 2):

The UI thread stack size on Android 2.x is smaller than Android 4.x. This means older versions are more prone to StackOverflowErrors. This explains why you only experience this on an older version.

The problem with ABS is that it automatically adds a few nested views to your layout (the main layout which holds the action bar). You can see these extra views by using **Hierarchy Viewer**.

If you already had a deep layout with many nested views, adding ABS probably added the extra views that filled up your stack.

What I suggest is that you simplify your layout and remove some of your extra views. There are a few tips on how to optimize layouts in the Android Developer Blog (by Romain Guy). If you save about 2-3 views, it should compensate on what ABS added and you should be fine.